# vb.6.0 lvwtag to vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Im new at Vb.net 2010. im using vb 6.0. Can anyone help me convert this code to vb.net 2010?

```
Dim SkeyBracket as ingeter
Dim xList As ListItem
If sKeyBracket <> 0 Then
    Set xList = lvBracket.FindItem(CStr(sKeyBracket), lvwTag)
Else
    Set xList = lvBracket.ListItems(1)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490%28office.11%29.aspx)(*It discusses VBA, but VB6 is very similar*) and in looking at the documentation for the VB6 [`ListView.FindItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443432%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and .net [`ListViewFindItemWithText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxdakxef.aspx) Method you will need to look more closely at the context of your VB6 code in order to determine the best fit.

> Set Keyword.   In VBA, the Set keyword is necessary to distinguish between assignment of an object and assignment of the default property of the object. **Since default properties are not supported in Visual Basic .NET, the Set keyword is not needed and is no longer supported**.

So in your case I would do something like:

```
Dim SkeyBracket as integer
Dim xList As ListViewItem

If sKeyBracket <> 0 Then
    xList = lvBracket.FindItem(CStr(sKeyBracket), lvwTag)
Else
    xList = lvBracket.ListItems(1)
End If
```

Comment: yes i know . but my question is . what can i use in vb.net 2010 in vb6.0 is "lvwtag"

Comment: Without seeing the context I have no idea what lvwtag or exactly what you are trying to find. You have a ListViewItem in .net it is not the same as the ListItem in VB6. You will need to compare the documentation to determine it. I would look at the links I just added to see if it is of any help

Comment: @MarkHall: the lvwtag is an enum, and it is used to tell the vb6 listview FindItem method that the search should be done by based upon the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck, listviews in .Net do not have an equivalent method.  The good news is that it is relatively trivial to write your own.  If you are only using it in one place, you could use LINQ to do so without having to declare your own method, otoh if you are using it a lot, then an extension method would allow you to "add" it to the listview class.

While the [ListView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ListView(v=vs.110).aspx) does not contain a FindItem method or equivalent method that searches by a ListItem's Tag property, it is easy to do the equivalent using LINQ (Cast is used to make the list item collection an ienumerable)

```
 lvBracket.Items.Cast(Of ListItem).FirstOrDefault(
               Function(li) Object.Equals(li.Tag, CStr(sKeyBracket))
```

Or using [VB's null coalesence operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.100).aspx) (the one called with 2 arguments):

```
 xList = If(lvBracket.Items.Cast(Of ListItem).FirstOrDefault(
               Function(li) Object.Equals(li.Tag, CStr(sKeyBracket)),
            lvBracket.Items(1))
```

Although I really suspect you meant `lvBracket.Items(0)`...

If you want it as a method, then an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936(v=vs.100).aspx) is easy enough to write:

```
Public Function FindByTag(this as ListView, tagStr as String) As ListItem
    Return this.Items.Cast(Of ListItem).FirstOrDefault(
               Function(li) CStr(li.Tag) = tagStr)
End Function
```

And used as `lvBracket.FindByTag(CStr(sKeyBracket))`